# Type Guards for child interface with optional parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to write type guards for the following three interfaces:

```
export interface DeleteBatchAction {
  documentReference: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference<any>;
}

export interface UpdateBatchAction extends DeleteBatchAction {
  data: firebase.firestore.UpdateData;
}

export interface SetBatchAction extends UpdateBatchAction {
  options?: firebase.firestore.SetOptions;
}

export type BatchAction = DeleteBatchAction | UpdateBatchAction | SetBatchAction;
```

Each of the interfaces extends the last. The biggest issue here is that `SetBatchAction` only has an optional parameter distinguishing it from `UpdateBatchAction`.

1) Is there a way to write a type guard so that a variable of type `BatchAction` can be resolved into `SetBatchAction` vs. `UpdateBatchAction` reliably?

2) Do I need to invoke the type guards in a specific order to ensure that I have the correct type? (An object of type `UpdateBatchAction` would pass the `isDeleteBatchAction` type guard if that is checked first?).

Comment: At runtime then, a `SetBatchAction` and an `UpdateBatchAction` might be exactly the same?  Then there's no way to tell them apart reliably.   Can you add a discriminating string literal to each type (and give up on the inheritance pattern)?  Or at least add a non-optional property to `SetBatchAction`?

Comment: Yes, after more research it seems I'll have to give up on this pattern. It just bothers me to make a single unified type that contains all of these properties as optional along with a 'type' field to distinguish & just have consuming logic know that 'if type SET then check for these specific fields on the object.'

Comment: If you’re willing to change the pattern then you should probably make a discriminated union; I can write up an answer to demonstrate if you want.

Comment: I would appreciate that. I'm unfamiliar with the concept of a discriminated union. I will do my own research as well but would definitely enjoy to see your write up & demonstration too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way to represent this sort of thing in TypeScript is to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).  That's a union type where each member of the union has a property in common, called the *discriminant*, that is used to tell the different members of the union apart.  The type of this property should be something like a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) or a [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types).  Here's a way of representing your `BatchAction` type as a discriminated union:

```
export interface DeleteBatchAction {
  type: "DeleteBatchAction"
  documentReference: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference<any>;
}

export interface UpdateBatchAction {
  type: "UpdateBatchAction";
  documentReference: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference<any>;
  data: firebase.firestore.UpdateData;
}

export interface SetBatchAction {
  type: "SetBatchAction";
  documentReference: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference<any>;
  data: firebase.firestore.UpdateData;
  options?: firebase.firestore.SetOptions;
}

export type BatchAction = DeleteBatchAction | UpdateBatchAction | SetBatchAction;
```

Each member of that union has a `type` property of a particular string literal type.  The compiler will then let you `switch` on or otherwise type guard against the `type` property, and it will automatically narrow a `BatchAction` to one of its union members:

```
function foo(x: BatchAction) {
  switch (x.type) {
    case "DeleteBatchAction": {
      x.documentReference; // okay
      return 1;
    }
    case "UpdateBatchAction": {
      x.documentReference; // okay
      x.data; // okay
      return 2;
    }
    case "SetBatchAction": {
      x.documentReference; // okay
      x.data; // okay
      x.options; // okay
      return 3;
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you prefer to reuse your interfaces and use the inheritance pattern you can still do it, but you will need to add a `type`-like property to `SetBatchAction` and check the types in a particular order to reliably tell the union members apart.  For example, each `SetBatchAction` should have a `setBatchAction` property whose type is `true`.  Like this:

```
export interface DeleteBatchAction {
  documentReference: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference<any>;
}

export interface UpdateBatchAction extends DeleteBatchAction {
  data: firebase.firestore.UpdateData;
}

export interface SetBatchAction extends UpdateBatchAction {
  setBatchAction: true; // add this
  options?: firebase.firestore.SetOptions;
}

export type BatchAction = DeleteBatchAction | UpdateBatchAction | SetBatchAction;
```

And then you can guard by checking first for `setBatchAction`, and then for `data`:

```
function foo(x: BatchAction) {
  if ("setBatchAction" in x) {
    x // SetBatchAction
    x.options
    x.data
    x.documentReference
    return 3;
  } else if ("data" in x) {
    x // UpdateBatchAction
    x.data
    x.documentReference
    return 2;
  } else {
    x // DeleteBatchAction
    x.documentReference
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This works just as well, but the implementation of `"foo"` here is a little easier to get wrong and (in my opinion) harder to understand than the one using the discriminated union.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJKiSwLIBmAlgE4QBGIUyBhppEAHjAPb0ALmXDQ4iJHUZQhg9iS7c+gkUICeMZAFUYAExBCIAEUMgkAXjxJ1ALiSz6tYAHMkAX0VLeA4Ug1aSMb88ACukMBCAEoQ1BCMwIgAPAAqAHyW1jz2KR4A3F5cPqr+msgAyhBCAPIwQrT8wFCZuEhY9o7Obp6cXD2kPYrk4lRBtFDwTmDOhhB62sANwHiFxX7ORvTUo8YQGFUQAEKG8AAWAILw9Y0rvUoBEPYARLv7RsdCZ5fXwE+FpHoQuEIJEYnEEoh7NJmKwIAA6aGyeRw4JhCLRWLxEHJEDAdRpAp3DxEVYqdaReLbSS6AzvE4XK5LW5KUgPZ402YfL6MxpPQkspCAtEgjHg7GPKQMGFsBFSpGMFFA9FgrGJCBJXH4-ks2kgKFSlgyxFyBUcoymIQgbUDElEtYiDaU0aVIRchk-ZkstlIJ4ut3fJZ8-6CpUilUQiXQw3w43I1HA0GYiMavEE4O6-WMaOymQm+Fmkxma1cfh1JZQAD8melMblebhLtqPygxcGdrJajKSH9POWVleBx7HoAPkgC0OmaO-fSA41CYVqKFEh7qPx+AAKbLdme9gCUnqUUAA7rRPqckJu4Q99xwBaR0GwfQO6WfZ797Le76QeHChQnRaqiB5EgAD0IFIPwADWIDqMGSiMEIoT0MsACMxZKP0d4PsgTzjjuPxPB+cFcD+f7Kkm4rAWBEHQbBRICqRRageBUEwcRpAIUhywAEzoX0xHYT606vr2hEHnepGhomYpqlRLG0exSCMZack0Wx9Esj+pbNqprF0V+HFVFxSAAMx8TaGmYRZihtkMYiUJI1ROC4MwYLcpK+A6FJbDseyDvhTKfkoZFhhRarVtmsYKvG5EyTiqatra3gdkgjo+dS+icgFNy8EYwB6M0z5HNlyxBVwGaSlmsI5tA9YFhaVqFG2yWeal3lUhUVQTjlPB5QVY6ZS+3IemVpBsK6JX2EI9ChBAfHaeWVaVTWNXyvCjZlo0LZNUlRQpQ824iR6-Z+UN7qTgNtLFUdF3CcNSz8guS69lIa6bvY3XADewa0NQF5PONn1PG1SnfRp37MUgd3nY0xFaZtTRw7+ZhIyF0mARAxGcchpl8e4SB7I+v3-bqwPOKD4lKDwkN4TdsPg0pyOWqjUkARGWNGTjvHBvjhMKAz1PUUVn0s8K6Pswz2OoXjO29G27hAA)

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree that relying on type checking in a particular order is likely to be problematic, so I think discriminant union type is the best route. Only qualm I have is that when declaring one of the objects I still have to manually specify the type variable to its one allowed value. Any way to make it default/any popular strategies that pair with this discriminant type so that I don't manually do that every time? Or just a price that has to be paid.